# How will be the minimum area the triangle formed?

Tags: geometry

Let assume  there are two  sides of a triangle   are given, which are  $8$ and $6$. It is pretty clear that other edge will be less than $14$ and greater than $2$.

But, How will be the minimum area  the triangle  formed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the angle between the two given sides be $\theta$. Then the area of the triangle is $\frac 12\times 8\times 6\times\sin\theta$. There is no minimum area, but we can make the area as small as we want. However, the maximum area occurs when $\theta=90^\circ$.